# JSON marshaling of object arrays with JAXB

Tags: json, jaxb, moxy, xmlanyelement

Using MOXy I'm trying to marshal a java class like this to JSON:

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Request {
   String method;
   @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
   Object[] arguments;
}
```

I would expect something like:

```json
{
    "method": "test",
    "arguments": ["a", "b"]
}
```

but the JSON output results to:

```json
{
    "method": "test",
    "value": ["a", "b"]
}
```

Where is the `value` coming from?

If I put a `@XmlElementWrapper` over the arguments field, it gets even worse:

```json
{
    "method":"test",
    "arguments":"a""value":["b"]
}
```

My JUnit `TestCase` looks like this:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class JsonRequestTest {

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public static class Request {
    String method;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    Object[] arguments;
} // InvocationRequest

@Test
public void testObjectArray() throws JAXBException {
    System.setProperty(JAXBContext.class.getName(), "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");
    Map<String, Object> props= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
    props.put("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);

    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class<?>[]{Request.class},props);
    Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Request req = new Request(); 
    req.method="test";
    req.arguments = new Object[]{"a","b"};
    m.marshal(req, writer);
    assertEquals("{\"method\":\"test\", \"arguments\":[\"a\",\"b\"]}", writer.toString());
}
} // class JsonRequestTest
```

Comment: In the case of string arguments, I was able to get, what I need, by adding @XmlElements(@XmlElement(name="arguments")) to the arguments. This does not work however, if I use non-string arguments, i.e. some annotated bean.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

### TL:DR

You can set the following property to override the `value` key.

```
    props.put(MarshallerProperties.JSON_VALUE_WRAPPER, "arguments");
```

---

### Full Test Case

Below is the full working test case.  In addition to setting the property I removed an extra space you had in your control document to get the test to pass.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JsonRequestTest {

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Request {
        String method;

        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        Object[] arguments;
    } // InvocationRequest

    @Test
    public void testObjectArray() throws JAXBException {
        System.setProperty(JAXBContext.class.getName(),
                "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        props.put("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        props.put(MarshallerProperties.JSON_VALUE_WRAPPER, "arguments");

        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(
                new Class<?>[] { Request.class }, props);
        Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Request req = new Request();
        req.method = "test";
        req.arguments = new Object[] { "a", "b" };
        m.marshal(req, writer);
        assertEquals("{\"method\":\"test\",\"arguments\":[\"a\",\"b\"]}",
                writer.toString());
    }

} // class JsonRequestTest
```

---

### `@XmlElementWrapper` Issue

I have opened the following bug for the issue with `@XmlElementWrapper`:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/421977

Comment: Eclipse implementation. Is it possible to doe the dame without org.eclipse ?

Comment: @ses - I'm not sure what you mean by your comment, can you expand on it?

Comment: I mean what if not use this package (org.eclipse) and MarshallerProperties that provides jaxb-implementation. But use default one that comes with java. Then, is it possible to do the same? I guess not because I could not find.. there javax.json package in java 6, but only javax.xml.

Comment: @ses - The JAXB reference implementation doesn't offer native JSON-binding.  To produce JSON with it you need to use an external library like Jettison:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html

Comment: Unfortunately the link to `EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)` is broken (and I couldn't find a new one)